# PhpStorm: running, testing and debugging

Tags: php, curl, windows-10, phpstorm

I installed PHP on Windows 10 and have been able to run the PHP scripts from within PhpStorm for debugging.

However, I can't seem to get `curl_init` to work.

I edited the `php.ini` to include the curl extension.

```
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.50.1
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => No
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => Yes
TLS-SRP => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => i386-pc-win32
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.1t
ZLib Version => 1.2.7.3
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.7.0
```

Still when I go to run my php files that have `curl_init()` they fail to run.

EDIT:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Users\Frank\PhpstormProjects\TimeLock\index.php on line 75
```

Comment: `they fail to run` in what kind of way?

Comment: Added the error message I get

Comment: How did you get your curl extension info? `php -i` run in terminal or what? So far it seems that you have edit wrong php.ini ... or your web server uses different php.ini (or maybe just still uses old setting) . Place `phpinfo();` in your script and execute it (try to debug it) then show the whole output e.g. post on on pastebin and give a link here)

Comment: So it was pulling the wrong php.ini but now nginx throws a 502 bad gateway so not sure what that is about. I may just have to setup a dedicated linux server

Comment: What do you mean by nginx exactly? What URL do you see in a browser when you see 502 response? Maybe you not using nginx but using something else (like, PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server)? P.S. consider using `@username` otherwise your comment will not issue notification